# Convert BigInt to Number Sol -> Javascript

Tags: numbers, solidity, bigint, contract

I have this function returning a uint:

```
function initiateBet(uint256 amount, BetOutcome choice) external returns (uint256) {
        require(amount > 0, "Betrag muss groesser als 0 sein");
        //require(choice != BetOutcome.NotSet, "Ungueltige Wahl");

        // Transfer des Einsatzes von Spieler 1
        hardhatToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(owner), amount);
        nextBetId++;
        // Wette erstellen
        bets[nextBetId] = Bet({
            player1: msg.sender,
            player2: address(0),
            amount: amount,
            player1Choice: choice,
            player2Choice: BetOutcome.NotSet,
            isSettled: false
        });

        emit BetInitiated(msg.sender, nextBetId, amount);
        return nextBetId;
    }
```

and im trying to store the number in my Frontend or like here in my Tests:

```
     const amount = 50;
     const result = await sportsBet.connect(addr1).initiateBet(amount, 1);
     console.log(result);`
```

It gives me this:

```
{
  hash: '0xb1d1efbbbe97733ecc5cc5da6b0a4c3693255afb3b38fc1925beb137fa82e334',
  type: 0,
  accessList: null,
  blockHash: '0xcfa9d38234e9584ac0bd69acf21400c268a61c756453aa04958ee50a9da63d47',
  blockNumber: 5,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "8000000000" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "1121656" },
  to: '0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 0,
  data: '0x390490b600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  r: '0x92824225088bbc83b14642c3defca0b3ddadbd6e4fddeea2b3e7ec11600a9d66',
  s: '0x2165c3d92f4df1c339493846752680cd97b767fecf46b723a079702535c4d288',
  v: 62710,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

`console.log(result.toNumber());` -> result.toNumber is not a function
`console.log(Number(result));` -> NaN
`console.log(result.toString());` -> [object Object]